# Tensorflow Estimator API with large number of features

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow Estimator API to train some models, but what found that I have to use `tf.feature_column` for every feature

I have dataset consists of this columns :

> ['age', 'workclass', 'education', 'education_num', 'marital_status',
>          'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'gender', 'capital_gain',
>          'capital_loss', 'hours_per_week', 'native_country', 'income_bracket']

why do I have to make them like this

```
gender = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("gender", hash_bucket_size=10)
occupation = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("occupation", hash_bucket_size=1000)
marital_status = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("marital_status", hash_bucket_size=1000)
relationship = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("relationship", hash_bucket_size=1000)
education = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("education", hash_bucket_size=1000)
workclass = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("workclass", hash_bucket_size=1000)
native_country = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("native_country", hash_bucket_size=1000)
```

.. etc, seems not the best way to handle the preprocessing for the features. is there a better way or we will be in this pain if we ever go to `tf.estimator`